Does time always dilate?
Consider a frame $O$ and a moving with speed $v$ relative to frame $O'$.
By $(x,t)$ we denote the spacetime coordinates of a point.
For two events $A, B$ happening in $O$, consider the following separate scenarios:

First scenario: $A$ is at $(0,0)$ and $B$ is at $(0,t)$,

Second scenario: $A$ is at $(0,0)$ and B is at $(vt, t)$.


Now, consider these events in $O'$. In the first scenario, the two events differ by $\Delta t = \gamma t$, while in the second scenario the two events differ by $t/\gamma$. So does time always dilate?

If you are asking whether the proper time (the time difference measured with the same clock) is always shorter than some other measurement of time difference between the same two events then the answer is yes. Otherwise, I am not sure what you are asking.

What does "the two events differ by" mean?

The time dilation formula applies only in cases in which you compare the interval between two events occurring at the same place in one frame with the interval in another in which the events occur in two different places. Thus in your example, scenario one sees a time interval in O dilated in O', while scenario two is actually looking at a time interval in O' being dilated in O.

Time dilation describes how fast do you see a clock ticking that moves at v, it is not about time measured between two arbitrary events. In your second scenario there is no clock moving at v from A to B relative to O', so the standard formula for time dilation does not apply.

+1 for hitting the nail on the head.


Consider an immobilised system O and a moving with speed v relative to O system O’.
...
1)First scenario, A is A(0,0) and B is B(0,t),

The above events describe the system in the O' frame, not the O frame. You said O is "immobilised" and O sees O' moving at speed $v$. E.g., O' is the frame of a ship moving from $x=0$ to $x=vt$, as seen in the "immobilised" O frame. (I'm putting "immobilised" in quote because either frame could be considered at rest...)
Thus, it would probably be less confusing and more consistent with your first sentence to call the components of the above-written events
$$
A' = (0,0)
$$
$$
B' = (0,t')
$$

Second scenario A is A(0,0) and B is (vt, t).

This so-called "Second scenario" gives the components of the same events in the frame that you started off calling "O." I will explicitly include the factor of $c$ and re-write what you have above as
$$
A=(0,0)
$$
$$
B=(vt,ct)
$$

In the first scenario, in O’ the two events differ by Dt = gamma*t, while in the second scenario the two events differ by t/gamma. So, does time always dilate?

The time measured with any other set of clocks is always less than the proper time, which is the time measures on the same clock (the clock traveling at $v$ from one event to the other).
The relationship between O and O' frames is well known. We have:
$$
ct' = \gamma ct - \beta \gamma vt\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
x' = -\beta\gamma ct + \gamma vt\tag{2}\;.
$$
We only need Eq. (1) above, which says:
$$
ct' = ct\gamma\left(1 - \beta^2\right) = \frac{ct}{\gamma}\;. 
$$
Or, in terms of time differences:
$$
\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}\;.
$$
Thus the proper time difference $\Delta t'$ (as measured in O') is less than the time measured in the "immobilised" frame O.

I don't think this question deserves down votes, as relativity beginners have questions.
There are 8, maybe 9, problems, though:

Introducing the moving frame 1st. That's just causes confusion. and delay.

Making the primed frame stationary: confusion and delay (heretofore c/d)

Inverting the order of coordinates (c/d). In the modern formulation of 4 vectors:


$$ a^{\mu} = (a_0, \vec a) $$
so in 2-D relativity, we do:
$$ E_A = (t_A, x_A) $$

Saying that an event occurs in a frame. This is a misunderstanding of events, and it does lead to conceptual problems down the road. For example, you'll see "A second event occurs at the same location". All space (time) like events occur at the same location (time) in some frame.

Events are points in space time, regardless of coordinates.

You reuse events labels. Don't. c/d.

Label coordinate values with subscripts, because they are not coordinates. c/d.

Introducing a length as $vt$ is asking for problems. Possible c/d.

The whole thing is too abstract, so lets make a scenario.


(Note: I started out with 4 problems, which doubled when I tried to solve it).
The point is, if you set your problems up clearly:

You will understand them better.

We will understand them better.

1 + 2 = 0 x (c/d)


So, here we go: In the Lab Frame, $O$,
Stop. $O$ means "origin", we're using the standard: $S$.
In the Lab Frame, $S$,
an accelerator fires a muon at $v$ into a detector at distance $L$. (Oh, now that we have a scenario, the order of your events is wrong, as $B$ is extraneous).
So the events are:

Fire the muon:

$$ A = (0, 0) $$

Detect the muon:

$$ B = (L/v, L) $$
Now we can define $t_B = L/v$.

The event of the source being simultaneous with the detections in the Lab:

$$ C = (L/v, 0) $$
OK, now that we something to wrap our imagination around, we can move to the moving frame, $S'$, which just happens to be the muon's rest frame:
$$ A' = (0,0)$$
$$ B' = (t_B/\gamma, 0) = (\frac L {\gamma\beta}, 0)$$
(use beta bc it looks better next to gamma).
so $t'_B = t_B/\gamma$. But we're not calling that time dilation: it's just a coordinate. We need to look at time difference between identical events. It's trivial, since: $(t_A, x_A) = (t'_A, x'_A)$, but it is a bad habit to not look at coordinate differences:
$$ \Delta t_{BA} = L/v $$
$$ \Delta t'_{BA} = L/v/\gamma 
=\Delta t_{BA}/\gamma $$
Now that's time dilation. Note, since $A=A'=A''= A^{'\cdots'}$, I don't need primes on the 2nd form: events are invariant points, as are their differences. They are not "coordinates in a specific frame".
Now for $C'$, you need to do some work (LT):
$$ C' = \big(
\gamma(t_C - vx_C), \gamma(x_C-v t_C)
\big)$$
$$ C' = \big(
\gamma L/\beta, -\gamma L
\big)$$
So the big take away here is the $C$ is meaningless in $S'$...it's just event that occurs after detection, and at a different place than emission.
Though it may be useful if you want to consider length contraction.
